# get multiple fields value inside Solr pivoting

Tags: solr

I have columns named categoryid, description, packid, imageurl... and many other columns. A category with description, imageurl can contain multiple packsid. Now I need to find out in solr, how many categories are there and how many packs in each cateogry. For this I do a facet.pivot on

```
CCategoryId,PPackId
```

I get the category id and the packid inside them. But how to get the description and imageurl for the categoryid. Is there a way wherein I can get these values along with categoryid in the pivot itself

This is my Solr api

```
http://172.28.0.162:8983/solr/cpaCore/select?q=PIsActive:true&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&fl=CategoryId,Description,ImageUrl, PackId, groupfield&facet=true&facet.pivot=CategoryId,PackId
```

I need to get description and ImageUrl for every Categoryid

Update
This is my table in solr
Categoryid, Description, ImageUrl, Packid, Packinfo, Packgrop......

This is what I need
Group by (Categoryid, Description and ImageUrl) combined and then group by packid on the result from the above group by

So the result something like

```
--field Category 
--value :.. , 
--field: description 
--value : , 
--field: imageurl 
--value ...  
--count : ...
-----field: packid
-----value: 1
-----count
-----field: packid
-----value: 2
```

For more clarity adding resulting result in the form of table that I need

```
catid  desc   imageurl packid
1      x      y        11
1      x      y        12
1      x      y        13
```

also it should give me count of unique(catid, desc, imageurl) and count of packid in this unique(catid, desc, imageurl)

Answer (score 1):

When you do faceting(grouping), the results would be based on group functions like count. And once grouping is done on a specific field, the others field values could be different. For Ex

catId, packId, desc, Img

1,1,desc1,img1

1,2,desc1,img1

1,3,desc1,img1

2,1,desc2,img2

2,2,desc2,img2

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/ram_core/select?q=*&facet=true&facet.field=catId&facet.pivot=catId,img,desc&facet.pivot=catId,packId&wt=json&indent=true
```

Here I gave two pivots, one for catId, img, desc, and one for catid, packId

Results:
catId1,img1,desc1 - 3
catId2,img2,desc2 - 2

catId1,packId1 - 1
catId2,packId2 - 1
catId3,packId3 - 1
catId4,packId4 - 1
catId5,packId5 - 1

Comment: Categoryid, description and imageurl are always same for same cateogry id. I need this information along with cou t which i am getting while doing facet.pivot but cannot get values for all fields

Comment: Ok but your faceting is on two fields, so I think the group functions were already evaluated, and then you need one level above now, to get only cat, img and desc and not packId. Can you confirm.

Comment: Yes so can i do facet.pivot on multiple columns in one level and then on packid like on description, categoryid and imageurl and then on packid

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple fields in pivot

Comment: Well you are already doing it on multiple fields i guess in your query. But the problem comes when you need two things. Because if you need faceting and counts for composite key, you are doing it already. You can decide how many columns can fit in there.

Comment: Elaborating further i need categoryid, description and imageurl as grouped into one and count of this with their value and then count of packid along with its value in this

Comment: Is there any better way of doing it than what i am doing

Comment: Updated my question.. plz hav a look

Comment: adding for every categoryid there will be only 1 description and imageurl

Comment: please post your results